# Airflow schedule spark Jobs based on typesafe config files

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, typesafe-config

I am using Airflow to schedule the submitting of JARs ( corresponding to the packaging of Spark applications) to Hadoop cluster. 
The different Spark jobs have the same JAR name, but depending on the config files ( I am using .conf files with TypeSafe config Library) different jobs are launched. My question  is how to make Airflow parse the .conf files in order to know which spark job to launch . 
so here I am launching spark application with `spark-submit --class ( same class for all jobs)  -Dconfig.file=path/to/config-file`

Any idea about this pleaseS

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I managed to pass config through jvm system properties. It works because typesafe config includes jvm system properties when getting loaded.

More precisely, I send required properties in the config file by `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`.

Comment: but how can pass this to airflow

Comment: @scalacode I hard coded the config in the task where I submit the spark job.

Comment: hello I used this : dataproc_spark_properties={'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions':'gs://test-dev/fileConf/development.conf'}. But it didn't work. How did you manage to do this please